# Trouble understanding poset notation and Hasse Diagrams

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I am trying to understand posets and if I have understood correctly - a poset is a set with a binary relation "≤" which is reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetrical.

I am having trouble understanding Hasse Diagrams and the way to denote a poset.

My current understanding for coming up with an example goes something like this:

1) Form a set: A = {1, 2, 3, 4}

2) Form a relation: ?

3) Draw a diagram based on the relation.

I'm not sure what the notation is supposed to be like in step 2). R = a set of pairs that fulfills reflexivity, transitivity, and asymmetry? What is the easiest way to come up with that and how do I write it out?

For drawing the diagram, I would usually draw an arrow for each relation - but from the examples I have seen not each relation has been directly joined and arrows are not necessarily used. How are they drawn?

I am just learning about this so it's still quite confusing as a whole and a simple and clear example would be helpful.

Also, if the relation is defined to be "≤" then why are there diagrams depicting other kinds of relations? What does it mean to be ordered by inclusion?

Would this be an example of a poset?

A = {1, 2, 3, 4}

and its Hasse diagram

4
|
3
|
2
|
1

?

Do I need to write out R, the relation?

I found this example of a Hasse diagram:

[image: Hasse diagram]

But it had no numbers or anything. How am I supposed to interpret it? How would a poset for this be written out?

Answer (score 4):

The whole idea of a Hasse diagram is just an efficient representation of your poset. If you think about the set of subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ ordered by inclusion (that is, $\subseteq$), we have ordered pairs like $(\varnothing, \{1\}),\, (\varnothing \{1,2\}),\, (\{1\}, \{1,2\})$, and so on, reflecting the fact that $\varnothing \subseteq \{1\}$, etc.

But since we know that $\subseteq$ is transitive, then knowing $\varnothing \subseteq \{1\}$ and $\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$ tells us that $\varnothing \subseteq \{1,2\}$; it would be silly for our efficient representation to waste time representing this, as long as we make sure to represent $\varnothing \subseteq \{1\}$ and $\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$:

[image]

So for example, the fact that we can trace a path from $\{1\}$ up to $\{1, 2, 3\}$ using edges in the Hasse diagram means that $\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2,3\}$, or equivalently, that the ordered pair $(\{1\}, \{1,2,3\})$ is in our relation.

We only draw edges in the Hasse diagram to depict so-called *covering* relations: So, we drew a line from $\{1\}$ to $\{1,2\}$ because if we have an inequality like

$$\{1\} \subseteq \Delta \subseteq \{1,2\},$$
then we're *forced* to use $\Delta = \{1\}$ or $\Delta = \{1,2\}$; nothing "fits" between them properly. Thus, we say that $\{1\}$ *is covered by* $\{1, 2\}$, and draw a line in the Hasse diagram.

---

We generally use the symbol $\le$ any time we have a poset, even if the relation has nothing to do with the normal definition of $\le$ to compare numbers. So we could write $\varnothing \le \{1\}$ in the example above, if we wanted to. Some people, to prevent this confusion, use the symbol $\preceq$ for a generic poset, to help you realize that the relation might have *nothing* to do with the usual way to order real numbers.

---

When you're given an unlabeled Hasse Diagram as in your last example, just call all of the nodes by some name; $\{1, 2, 3,4\}$ or $\{a, b, c, d\}$, it doesn't really matter. Just that we can see the comparisons between them.

So we could pick [image]

and start getting ordered pairs $(a, c),\, (a, d),$ etc, since we can see that $a \le c$, $a \le d$, and so on. In this example, the *only* relations are covering relations, so we'll have as many ordered pairs as there are lines in the graph.

In your linear example with $1 \le 2 \le 3 \le 4$, we would have $4 + 3 + 2 + 1$ ordered pairs: $\{(i, j): i \le j\}$ even though there are only $3$ edges in the Hasse Diagram.

Comment: Other classic examples that yield posets with nice Hasse diagrams: Ordering the set of divisors of a number, say $12$, with the relation $a \le b$ if and only if $a$ divides $b$ (see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554033/proving-that-restrictions-of-partial-orders-are-partial-orders/1554060#1554060) of mine for a Hasse Diagram). Also ordering the faces of a polygon/polyhedron/polytope by inclusion. That one's my favorite!