# What is the opposite of an "extension" of a partial order?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set):

> A partial order ≤<sup>*</sup> on a set *X* is an extension of another partial order ≤ on *X* provided that for all elements *x* and *y* of *X*, whenever *x ≤ y*, it is also the case that *x* ≤<sup>*</sup> *y*.

So we can say:

> ≤<sup>*</sup> is an extension of ≤

How can we phrase that in reverse? I'd like to say something like:

> ≤ is a _____ of ≤<sup>*</sup>

Here's a quick example drawing to emphasize that ≤<sup>*</sup> and ≤ may be over the same domain:

[image: Example of two related posets]

Comment: I think 'sub-poset' is what you are looking for.

Comment: Restriction. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554033/proving-that-restrictions-of-partial-orders-are-partial-orders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "restriction" refers to shrinking the domain. What you're after is *refinement*: $\le$ is a refinement of $\le^*$ if $a\le b\implies a\le^* b$, but not necessarily conversely.

Comment: How could it be finer when it is actually coarser?  A suborder, being a subset of ordered pairs, is much clearer.

Comment: @WilliamElliot It's not coarser. The coarser relation is the one which holds of more tuples; if $a\le b\implies a\le^*b$, then $\le$ is finer than $\le^*$. And "suborder" is usually understood to mean the restriction of the original order relation to a sub*set* of the domain.

Comment: As a coarser topology has fewer open sets would not a coarser order have  fewer comparisons?